# Multiply certain elements of a vector in R

Tags: r, vector, multiplication

I have a vector [1:360] with integers and need to find the products of the first, second ... twelfth set of 30 elements. Ultimately, I need a function that gives me a vector [1:12] with the products of all twelve 30-element intervals.
I'm fairly new to R and have been stuck on this for too long.

Comment: Please add data using `dput` and show the expected output for the same. Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way to do this would be to turn your vector into a 30-row matrix and get the product of each column.

In the absence of a reproducible example, let's make one with a vector of 360 numbers drawn from a normal distribution:

```r
set.seed(69)
vec <- rnorm(360)
```

We can turn `vec` into a 30 * 12 matrix by just doing `matrix(vec, nrow = 30)`, which will fill the matrix by column. We then get the product of each column by using `apply` to apply the function `prob` to each column.

```
apply(matrix(vec, nrow = 30), 2, prod)
#> [1] -6.253460e-09 -4.413086e-09 -1.332389e-10  1.041448e-08 -1.779489e-08  1.255979e-10
#> [7]  3.463687e-13 -6.265196e-12  8.300651e-04 -1.041469e-10  4.256378e-09  1.439522e-09
```